# Creating functions in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to write something like scheduler for testing different functions,so I need to read function from file.
For example, my txt file is :

tf.pow(tf.multiply(x, a), tf.multiply(b, z))

And I want to use this expression in my programm like
y=Tensor("smth I red from file") and then use it for minimazing as an exapmle.

```
  # Model parameters
a = tf.Variable(2, dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(2, dtype=tf.float32)

# Model input and output
x = tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32, initial_value=1.0, name='x')
z = tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32, initial_value=1.0, name='z')
  functions = []
  with open("functions.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        functions.append(line)
        y=tf.Tensor(line,1,dtype=tf.float32)
```

What is wrong?How can i implement it?

My Error is:

TypeError: op needs to be an Operation: tf.pow(tf.multiply(x, a), tf.multiply(b, z))

Comment: Your issue is when you save the tf functions in text file those convert in 'str' format , and tf functions are '<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'> ' so its little diffcult to load same type data from text file , i tried with ast, and pickle but didn't worked.

Comment: so ,there is no way to convert str to Tensor?
I think writting parser is bad way